# Intersection form of a Pseudomanifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, quadratic-forms, low-dimensional-topology, singularity-theory

Do pseudomanifolds have an intersection form? They have a volume cycle so it seems like you can use this to define a pairing on $H^{middle}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, however I've only see references to the intersection form on $IH(X)$.

One reason I'm interested is I want to know whether non-unimodular quadratic forms can make an appearance on pseudomanifolds without a Poincare duality. Are there any examples of this in 4 dimensions?

Comment: Whenever $X$ is connected and $G$-orientable, in that it admits a fundamental class $[X]\in H_n(X;G)$ with respect to some coefficients $G$, you can define an "intersection form" from the pairing $H^{mid}(X;G)\otimes H^{mid}(X;G)\xrightarrow{\cup}H^{top}(X;G))\xrightarrow{\cap [X]}H^0(X;G))\cong G$.

Comment: Thanks Tyrone. I agree. I would love an example with non-unimodular intersection form though.

Comment: Take an odd dimension pseudomanifold and suspend it once. Then the form defined above is the zero form, and so uninvertible.